# Django Rest Framework — no module named rest_framework. Rest_framework is installed and venv is active

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pip, python-venv, django-manage.py

I clone repository from github on my second computer, runserver does works but when typing

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Bash notice about 'no module name rest_framework'

This situation is a second time. Lately I install again rest_framework but then I had install other modules. Finally I create new project but now I want resolve this problem.

[image: my code an installed dependencies]

Comment: The virtualenv you have activated on the shell is the correct one (ex_books_django2) ?

Comment: It's right, shell uses other virtualenv, because whenever i type 'python manage.py runserver' there is the same error, however when i use shortcuts Shift+F10, then it works. How can i change this?

Comment: Well, PyCharm has an option for auto-activating the virtualenv you selected as Project Interpreter when the integrated shell is opened. If you have that, it'd be a matter of closing and open the shelll again